# SQL queries to display individuals who turned 21 three months ago and individuals turning 21 in six months from the run date plus one month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to develop 2 monthly reports each with the following:

- Individuals who turned 21 six months ago from the report run day
- Individuals who will be turning 21 in six months from the report the run date but add a month.

For the Individual who turned 21 months ago from the report run day, I tried but it did not work:

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR,BIRTHDAY, DATEADD(Month,-6,GETDATE())) = 21
```

For the Individuals who will be turning 21 in six months but add a month

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR,BIRTHDAY, DATEADD(Month,1,DATEADD(Month,6,GETDATE()))) = 21
```

Comment: Can you give use sample data? Which ones is it missing?

Comment: Please tag your DBMS and add some sample data

Comment: `DATEDIFF` doesn't work the way you are thinking it works. It works on date part boundaries. [See the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) especially the `datepart boundaries` portion of the page.  I think your best bet here would be `DATEDIFF(day...) = (21*365)`

Comment: Data examples:   for the six months after the person turns 21, the file produced on 7/1/2019 would include those people who became 21 in January 2019.                                                                                                            For the  people who will be 21 in 6 months with the file being produced 1 month prior, the file produced on 7/1/2019 will have those individuals who will be 21 in March 2020

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for SQL Server.

I've created some test data and I can't see what wouldn't be working.

A good way to test this at your own machine is to create a temporary table with some sample data and see what the output looks like. This is the test I used;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#People') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #People
CREATE TABLE #People (Name varchar(20), Birthdate datetime)
INSERT INTO #People (Name, Birthdate)
VALUES
 ('Alice','1997-12-07')
,('Brenda','1998-01-01')
,('Charlie','2001-12-25')
,('Deborah','1997-07-01')
,('Erik','1985-01-01')


SELECT
    *
    ,DATEADD(Month,-6,GETDATE()) AS SixMonthsAgoDate
    ,DATEDIFF(YEAR, Birthdate, DATEADD(Month,-6,GETDATE())) AgeSixMonthsAgo
    ,DATEADD(Month,1,DATEADD(Month,6,GETDATE())) SevenMonthsFutureDate
    ,DATEDIFF(YEAR, Birthdate, DATEADD(Month,7,GETDATE())) AgeSevenMonthsFuture
FROM #People
```

The final 4 calculations are yours (apart from the final one, you were adding 6 months and then adding 1 month separately, I've changed it to just adding the 7 months).

The output looks like this;

```
Name    Birthdate               SixMonthsAgoDate        AgeSixMonthsAgo SevenMonthsFutureDate       AgeSevenMonthsFuture
Alice   1997-12-07 00:00:00.000 2018-12-07 14:38:22.370 21              2020-01-07 14:38:22.370     23
Brenda  1998-01-01 00:00:00.000 2018-12-07 14:38:22.370 20              2020-01-07 14:38:22.370     22
Charlie 2001-12-25 00:00:00.000 2018-12-07 14:38:22.370 17              2020-01-07 14:38:22.370     19
Deborah 1997-07-01 00:00:00.000 2018-12-07 14:38:22.370 21              2020-01-07 14:38:22.370     23
Erik    1985-01-01 00:00:00.000 2018-12-07 14:38:22.370 33              2020-01-07 14:38:22.370     35
```

Which works just fine for what you're trying to do.

Feel free to try the above query using your actual data so you can debug this yourself. There's not much more we can do here on Stack Overflow without sample data and the expected output.

If you're trying to work this out for people's birth month then you'd be best doing this in months rather than years. Something like this;

```
SELECT
    *
    ,DATEADD(Month,-6,GETDATE()) AS SixMonthsAgoDate
    ,DATEDIFF(MONTH, Birthdate, DATEADD(Month,-6,GETDATE())) AgeSixMonthsAgo_Months
    ,DATEADD(Month,1,DATEADD(Month,6,GETDATE())) SevenMonthsFutureDate
    ,DATEDIFF(MONTH, Birthdate, DATEADD(Month,7,GETDATE())) AgeSevenMonthsFuture_Months
FROM #People
```

And then your where clauses would look like this;

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH, Birthdate, DATEADD(Month,-6,GETDATE())) = (21 * 12)
```

and

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH, Birthdate, DATEADD(Month,7,GETDATE())) = (21 * 12)
```

or even simplified further to this;

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH, Birthdate, GETDATE()) = (21 * 12) - 6

DATEDIFF(MONTH, Birthdate, GETDATE()) = (21 * 12) + 7
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @danielsvic lots of questions, never marked an answer. Let's start contributing rather than just taking.